# How to annotate / add arrow to a FIGURE not an AXIS

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to add an arrow to a figure in matplotlib, rather than an axis please?

I have a multi-component figure containing numerous axes, and want to be able to draw arrows between them. However, if I do this manually by setting the `ax.arrow()` to extend out of the axis, then it is cropped and doesn't show.

Comment: if you set `clip_on = False` for your `ax.arrow`, it should extend outside the axis

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!

Comment: great. I made it an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you set `clip_on = False` for your `ax.arrow`, it should extend outside the axis

Heres a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)

ax.arrow(0.5,0.6,0.55,0.,fc='r',ec='r',clip_on=True)
ax.arrow(0.5,0.4,0.55,0.,fc='b',ec='b',clip_on=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This no longer works in Matplotlib version `3.6.2`. Instead, `matplotlib` will change the limits to accommodate the arrow. Setting the limits (`ax.set_xlim`) restores the described behaviour for a single plot.

In addition, this is not compatible with the `constrained` layout.